# Adding placeholder text to chosen chosen-jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-chosen

I am using the chosen-rails gem with great success. However, I want to customise the placeholder text. From the gem documentation it looks like the following should be in the coffee script file

```
  $('.chzn-select').chosen
    allow_single_deselect: true
    no_results_text: 'No results matched'
```

When I use this code I can alter the deslectbehaviour, so the script is being called, but the placeholder text does not change

has anyone experienced similar behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a better solution to this.

Following this https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/176, one can use .attr("data-placeholder", "my message here...").chosen(); instead of .data().

Answer (score 9):

You can just set your `data-placeholder` attribute and Chosen will parse it automatically:

`:data => {:placeholder => 'User Name'}`

Comment: Not seeming to work for me. I have a collection for a dropdown `= f.input :occupancy_of_home, collection: @quote.options[:occupancy_of_home], data: {placeholder: 'Type of Home'}`

Answer (score 1):

The right solution here is to place an empty option element on top.

Answer (score 1):

To set a default text in the coffeescript file use:

`$('.chzn-select').chosen
    allow_single_deselect: true
    no_results_text: 'No results matched',
    placeholder_text_single: 'Please select an option',
    placeholder_text_multiple: 'Please select some options'`

Works for me with chosen-rails 1.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says in the "Default Text Support" section that you should use `data-placeholder` attribute on the select element. I haven't tested it yet and I'm also curious how to do it from script not from the markup.

*EDIT:*
I've just found a solution:  -- simple [overriding data attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-chosen) from a script (pretty obvious :)).

Comment: hmm, yeah it looks quite elegant, just doesn't seem to work for me. Still going round in circles a bit

Comment: Ditto. I have the same problem. Has anyone found a correct solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5 - 2018

This code works with the simple_form gem:

```
<%= f.input :tag, as: :select, collection: Tag.all, input_html: {class: 'chosen-select', :data => {:placeholder => "your custom placeholder"}, multiple: true} %>
```